# php limit regex match with brackets doesn't work

Tags: php, regex

```
return preg_match('/^([\d\p{Hebrew}]*\p{Hebrew}[\d\p{Hebrew}]*){1,64}$/iu', $str);
```

When trying the code above, the function returns true to strings larger than 64.
What is wrong here?

Comment: You used * inside the (), which means that the string can be bigger than 64.. the {1,64} quantifier refers to the whole expression in the round brackets, which doesn't have to be 1 char. What does this regex try to find?

Comment: a string that has at least one char in hebrew, numbers before and numbers after the minimum one char. Basically mixed Hebrew and numbers

Comment: Why not check with preg_match for digits/hebrew after you check that strlen($str) < 64 ? (or maybe mb_strlen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what s wrong with your expression (I can reproduce it with ascii chars), but this is working

```
 /^(?=.{1,64}$)([\d\p{Hebrew}]*\p{Hebrew}[\d\p{Hebrew}]*)$/
```

Remove the check for the length at the end.

Add `(?=.{1,64}$)` at the beginning. This is a positive look ahead, that just checks if the whole string is between 1 and 64 chars long. If yes it checks the pattern, if no the result is `False`.

[See here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ua44)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/^([\d\p{Hebrew}]*\p{Hebrew}[\d\p{Hebrew}]*){1,64}$/iu', $str, $matches);
return $matches;
```

it returns only if string is found, you have to fill third parameter (`$matches`) and return it.

Comment: Thats not what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @stema: no he wont. you'll see his response